# Creating image for google map tiles from KML file

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

I am totally new to this. I have a KML file of zip code boundaries. I want to create image from this KML, so that can use to overlay google maps. Can someone please guide me here?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps natively supports KML layers, you simply need to create a new google maps kml layer. Here's an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

As a side note, using Google Earth you can view your kml by simply dragging and dropping the file onto the globe.

Comment: but how to convert it into tiles to use with MapTIles?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party program? The example should be sufficient to view your layer.

Comment: The problem is I want to draw my huge map using Tiles, I am not sure If I will use kml layer it will be loaded as tiles.